# Provisioning profile not getting set while building Xcode project using Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcode8, xcodebuild

I am connecting to gitlab to pull source code and build the app through Jenkins. At build time, i am changing the bundle ID, certificate and provisioning profile for the App. But for some reason, the provisioning profile is not getting set while the former two works perfectly. I have added the profiles in KISS plugin and also provided the path to the profile in the Xcode plugin.

I have configured as below
[image: Xcode plugin-Jenkins]

I am getting the following error while building the App

*App requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'*

Attaching the console screenshot
[image]

Comment: @DhanesKM: Have you solved this issue?